# How to validate DTO's for a Client Server application

Tags: c#, web-services, validation, dto

I've been doing a lot of reading about DTO's recently, having never used them before. One article I read spoke about how DTO's should not just replicate domain model objects but rather each DTO should be tailored to the service operation being performed.

This got me thinking about validation if I decided to used DTO's and wondered if the following would be acceptable?

```
public class Person {
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public Address Address {get; set;}
}

public class Address {
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string AddressLine1 {get;set;}
    ...
}

publuc class CreatePersonDTO {
    private string _name;
    private string _addressLine1;

    public string Name {
        get {
             if (_name == null)
                 throw new Exception("Missing");

             return _name;
        }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public string AddressLine1 {
        get { return _addressLine1; }
        set { _addressLine1 = value; }
    }
}
```

So you pass your data through in either Json or Xml and it is serialised to the object CreatePersonDTO and when mapping those values to create a Person and Address object if the Persons Name is missing then it will throw a validation exception.

As the DTO itself is service operation specific so is having this validation here ok or is it breaking some kind of rule regarding where business logic should reside?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DTOs should have no validation; they are **strictly for transferring data**. Beyond validation, they should really have no behavior at all.

If the name is required, that is an aspect either of the domain or of a given service operation; validation should be encapsulated in the corresponding places (though you may also enforce the rule in the UI for a better experience).

Comment: Agreed. Last thing you need are your DTOs throwing exceptions in the data serialization/deserialization layer knee deep in WCF (or other communication provider).  Another benefit is by keeping DTOs data-only, most likely you can _reuse_ the same code file in both places it's used (say both Silverlight _and_ ASP.NET web services) this way you're guaranteed that if you add/remove/change a property that each source is updated accordingly. As soon as you put validation (or even logging) there, there's a good chance it won't be compatible for different environments/platforms.

Comment: Ok I can see how it would be a bad idea. Is there a clean pattern for validating DTO's that doesn't involve `if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(personDto) throw new Exception...` in the middle of my controllers?

Comment: @David Are you saying you want to validate that the DTO is coming back from your service in a valid state?

Comment: @Jay Sorry I just noticed a mistake in my comment. No I want to validate the DTO being sent to my service. If I am sent a Json object with a missing property of say type boolean, it can either resolve to default false or to a null(able) bool. I then need to map that property to my domain object for saving. At what point do I catch the property is missing?

Comment: @David I have struggled with exactly this -- we end up doing lots of mapping and it can become tedious. My inclination is to say that you could create validator classes that validate a constructed DTO for you, or that you create DtoFactory classes that take your input and either give you back a DTO (all good) or an error (invalid input). Ideally, you'd allow the domain validation to do its thing and any problems bubble back to the front-end, but I can see not wanting to do extra mapping or round-trip bad data. If the service is hosted locally to the web server, then just use domain logic.

Comment: @Jay Well at the moment we pass representations of the domain model across the wire but the catch is that for say an update, if the property is int, bool etc then we end up having to make them nullable to handle missing properties. If I could delegate this to a DTO so that it wouldn't even reach the business logic if something was wrong then that would be ideal and worth the trade off of having to maintain DTO's and a domain model.

Answer (score 2):

I would interpret **each DTO should be tailored to the service operation being performed** to mean if you have bulky domain objects DTO's can represent a subset that is pertinent to a particular service operation. I.e. it may only be interested in a few properties of the domain object.

Comment: Yes this what I took it to mean too.

Answer (score 1):

That depends. But usually it's not good place to put validation login into DTO. You wil have issue with reusability. For example if you need to update person you will have to create UpdatePersonDTO and put all the same logic there.

As another option you may put your validation logic into Person itself so you will not be able to create invalid person and it will be reusable. Or you may put entities validation logic into some kind of service layer.

Answer (score 1):

You should not put validation logic into your DTOs, this should be handled primarily by your Domain layer and in some cases, duplicated in your UI layer.  Your DTOs should be just that, dumb objects to transfer data.

Beyond the separation of responsibilities here, your logic can't actually be serialized.  The only things that would be transferred over the wire are the values themselves.  If you were passing this object to a non .NET consumer (over WCF for example) then they would not necessarily have the same rules built into the object that they deserialize the data into.